# Leading period as folder name in a URL

Tags: html, url, syntax, path, directory

I am working on a project where the name of our assets folder is .assets, and must remain that way. We need it to be as such so that it's hidden on UNIX and Linux systems. The only problem with this is that:

```
background-image: url(.assets/images/startup_arabic.jpg);
background-image: url(/.assets/images/startup_arabic.jpg);
background-image: url(../.assets/images/startup_arabic.jpg);
```

do not work. It's an html file, executed locally.

This really isn't my area of expertise...can anyone show me how this can be done?

Edit: The biggest reason that the folder needs to start with a ".", is so that it is hidden on devices like mp3 and ebook readers, etc.

Edit: Solved: One of our brilliant coders replaced the Arabic splash with the Farsi one.

```
background-image: url(.assets/images/startup_arabic.jpg);
```

is correct. Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: This really comes down to a permissions issue.  Paths/files beginning with `.` should not be accessible over the web, as they typically contain things that would be a security risk if exposed.  Since you are looking at these files locally, that should work fine if the user has permissions to access that directory.  Really though, you should put this image somewhere else.

Comment: So you're hiding from the local users what they will get over a web connection? Cannot compute.

Comment: Please. Just because you don't know how and why a project operates in such a way, that does not mean it is wrong. The project is a media library, distributed on microSD cards, with a html TOC. The scripts, images, xml, css, etc reside in the .assets folder. For some reason, crazy developers like to provide a clean interface for their clients. Imagine that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I don't know your directory structure but use `./.assets` if your file you are using to access the `.assets` folder is in the same dir as the `.assets` folder

Also put your url in quotes

Comment: Yeah, I advised quotes to begin with. Our coders decided they didn't need to, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use quoted or unquoted URI's, however special caracters ( including *possibly* the period) need to be escaped.

**Taken from W3:**

Some characters appearing in an unquoted URI, such as parentheses, commas, white space characters, single quotes (') and double quotes ("), must be escaped with a backslash so that the resulting URI value is a URI token: '(', ')', '\,'.

Comment: background-image: url(\.assets/images/startup_arabic.jpg); does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

Folder/Files starting with a dot should be considered "protected"

Comment: We need it to be "file:///E:/.assets/", not "file:///E:/somedir/.assets"

Comment: You can't do that in a public website, because `file:///E:/` will always refereer to the client hdd. If you need your website to get accessed only by localhost then it could work

Comment: I'm aware of this. We're not actually linking to the E drive, I was just showing that it needed to be the top level folder, not a subfolder of the project.

Comment: @kuart: if you solved it you should pick the answer that helped you.